# Adafruit Neopixel library slows down code

Tags: ws2812

I am trying to link WS2812 with the HC-SR04 sensor. My aim is to change the color of the leds depending on the distance the sensor measures. 
I am using the Adafruit Neopixel library for controlling the leds.
My problem is as soon as a function linked to the Adafruit library is used in the while loop the readings get very slow. Is there a way to speed the code process time up?

My code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import signal
import sys
from neopixel import *
import neopixel

LED_COUNT = 124  # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN = 18  # GPIO pin connected to the pixels 
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  
LED_DMA = 10  
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255 
LED_INVERT = False  # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor 
level shift)
LED_CHANNEL = 0  # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# set GPIO Pins
pinTrigger = 16
pinEcho = 12

def TurnOn(strip, color):
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
       strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
       strip.show()
    time.sleep(.5)

def close(signal, frame):
    print("\nTurning off ultrasonic distance detection...\n")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)

# set GPIO input and output channels
GPIO.setup(pinTrigger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinEcho, GPIO.IN)

strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, 
LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
strip.begin()


while True:
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, True)
    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, False)

    startTime = time.time()
    stopTime = time.time()

    # save start time
    while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        startTime = time.time()

    # save time of arrival
    while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        stopTime = time.time()

    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = stopTime - startTime
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    print ("Distance: %.1f cm" % distance)

    if distance < 8:
        TurnOn(strip, Color(127, 0, 0))
    else:
        TurnOn(strip, Color(0, 127, 0))

    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: Why sleep() in TurnOn? If you removed that then it would surely run faster...

Comment: overlooked that. of course its faster now, thanks!

Comment: WS2812 LEDs require a lot of realtime processing that can slow down other CPU tasks. While it looks like you've found the real reason (I hate it when `time.sleep()` happens!), sometimes it's better to hand off the blinkies to a dedicated microcontroller.

Comment: @scruss thanks for the reply! even though the readings got faster it is still not as fast as without using the TurnOn function. which microcontroller would you recommend for such a task?

Comment: Almost any will do. There are dedicated boards like the FadeCandy for controlling LEDs, but then the problem becomes managing the protocol  for the external controller board. If you don't want to do that, maybe look at gpiozero's [DistanceSensor](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#distancesensor-hc-sr04) - it handles polling for you. Also, unless it's a feature you like, `TurnOn` is calling `strip.show()` 124 times in very quick succession. `strip.fill()` would do the job of `TurnOn` in one command.

Comment: @ Atomic94 I am now learning how to play with NeoPixel.  I googled and found the following video very good.  The clever guy is a LED expert.  He does not use any Arduino or AdaFruit library.  He just writes his own short program, with a function to do fast write, without using interrupt（which he says is too slow), not to mention sleep delay. WS2812B LED with Arduino Tutorial - Kevin Darrah 2016mar01 296,054 views
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAa4duqMrgs

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Trying to link WS2812 with the HC-SR04 sensor.
>
> Aim is to change LED color depending on sensor distance.
>
> Using Adafruit Neopixel library for controlling the leds.
>
> A while loop SR04 read function linked to the Adafruit library get
>   very slow.
>
> How to speed up?

***Answer***

*Introduction*

I read that AdaFruit NeoPixel library supports Arduino and Circuit Python.  And CircuitPython library is NOT 100% compatible to Rpi python.  So you might need to do some modifications to you Rpi python code to make it compatible to AdaFruit arduino/circuit library.

Now let me start from the very beginning, using the following tutorial:

[Using Using Neopixels with the Raspberry Pi - Pi Hut](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/using-neopixels-with-the-raspberry-pi)

I am using a WS2812B 8 LED stick shown below.

[image: neopixel stick]

*Pi Hut Tutorial is Good*

I found Pi Hut's tutorial is very good, except that it uses AdaFruit's Ciccuit Library and need to make changes in library and code, as summarized below:

*Changes to make AdaFruit Library Rpi Compatible*

> pip3 install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka
>
> sudo pip3 install rpi_ws281x
>
> Make some changes to AdaFruit code
>
> Comment out this line pixel_pin = board.NEOPIXEL
>
> Remove the comment on this line pixel_pin = board.D18
>
> Change the number of Neopixels num_pixels = 10

Pi Hut's tutorial notes on power consideration and hardware setup is also good, as summarized below:

*Power Consideration*

> The Raspberry Pi can only power a few Neopixels.
>
> Need to power them separately.
>
> Don’t risk putting too many Neopixels onto a pi.
>
> They will pull more current than it can provide

*Hardware Setup*

> Convert jumper cable end with ring terminal
>
> Neopixels can pull up to 60mA, 20mA if not fully bright
>
> Separate 5V, 4A power supply strips of 60 lights
>
> Remember to connect Rpi ground to LED power ground

***Update 2019apr24hkt2016***

I googled a couple of WS2812B tutorial and youTubes and found the following video the best so far.  The guy is a LED expert, does not use any Arduino/AdaFruit library or code, every function by himself, and how he does sub microsecond write seems fantastic (but I have no yet understood what he says), ...

[Easy Addressable LEDs with Arduino! WS2812B Tutorial - Kevin Darrah 2016mar01 296,084 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAa4duqMrgs)

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[Using Using Neopixels with the Raspberry Pi](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/using-neopixels-with-the-raspberry-pi)

[WS2812B-V4 Intelligent control LED Integrated Light Source](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/108)

[AdaFrui NixoPixel Tutorial - Lada Ada](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels)

[AdaFruit NeoPixel Stick 8 x 5050 RGB LED with Integrated Drivers $5.95](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1426)

*Description*

> Eight tiny 5050 (5mm x 5mm) smart RGB LEDs
>
> Use only one microcontroller pin to control as many as you can chain
>   together
>
> Each LED is addressable as the driver chip is inside the LED.
>
> Each one has ~18mA constant current drive so the color will be very
>   consistent even if the voltage varies
>
> No external choke resistors are required
>
> Power whole thing with 5VDC (4 - 7V works)
>
> The LEDs are 'chainable' by connecting the output of one stick into
>   the input of another
>
> A single data line with a very timing-specific protocol, requires a
>   real-time microconroller such as an AVR, Arduino, PIC, mbed, etc.
>
> It cannot be used with a Linux-based microcomputer or interpreted
>   microcontroller such as the netduino or Basic Stamp.
>
> Our wonderfully-written Neopixel library for Arduino supports these
>   pixels!
>
> As it requires hand-tuned assembly it is only for AVR cores
>
> Others may have ported this chip driver code so please google around.
>
> An 8MHz or faster processor is required.
>
> Our detailed NeoPixel Uberguide has everything you need to use
>   NeoPixels in any shape and size. Including ready-to-go library &
>   example code for the Arduino UNO/Duemilanove/Diecimila,
>   Flora/Micro/Leonardo, Trinket/Gemma, Arduino Due & Arduino Mega/ADK
>   (all versions)

*Technical Details*

> WS2812B or SK6812-based LEDs. They are the same brightness, color and
>   protocol.

***Update 2019apr24hkt2015***

[Easy Addressable LEDs with Arduino! WS2812B Tutorial - Kevin Darrah 2016mar01 296,084 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAa4duqMrgs)