# Raspberry Pi and car led ground effects

Tags: led, cars

I am about to add led strips to my car. I will have at least 4 zones to start out and might add more.
1. Under carriage
2. Front end
3. External
4. Internal
Doing it now, I will have 4 controllers with either 1 app, or 4 different remotes.  Either way, I will have problems trying to get them to sync the way I envision.  Raspberry has so much power, that I think I should be able to preset every option I want and enable with my phone.  Some simple examples, all zones cool white, or zone 1 flashing green, zone 2 flashing purple, other 2 zones off, or just zone 4 blue. Possible?

Comment: Yes, no problem.  It is a piece of cake for Rpi.  I always think that anything stupid human can do, Rpi can do better - remember Google chess playing AlphaGo and Google driverless car?.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But is it the real question? What does it is? How to program it? That would be to broad.

Comment: @tlfong01 so where do I start?  I can find a lot of reading for house lights, but nothing for a car.  What software do I use?  I’m also clueless on writing my own code.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Add led strips to my car, ...
>
> One app or 4 different remotes, ...
>
> All zones cool white, zone 1 flashing green, ..., or just zone 4 blue.
> Possible?

***Answer***

Yes, with Rpi, no mission is impossible.  Your specific user requirement boils down to two generic answers:

> 1. Mobile phone controlling a couple of remotes
> 2. Rpi controlling a couple of LED strip

You might like to watch the following Open Garage YouTube to get a rough idea of how it can be DIYed using Arduino ESP8266 to do the job.  Of course you can also RpiZero WiFi, but ESP8266 WiFi is cheaper and smaller.

[Introducing OpenGarage: an Open-Source WiFi Garage Door Opener using ESP8266 - 55,426 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpwEa_48-Cw)

Yes, I know you are not opening a garage door, but the circuit of ESP8266/RpiZW controlling a remote which in turn switches on.off a garage door motor or LED strip is almost the same.

For LED strip, you can read the Lady Ada tutorial and a question on LED strip to get a rough idea of how to use Rpi to control the WS2812 LED strip.  This part is a little bit difficult, unless you use AdaFruit libraries.

[AdaFruit NixoPixel Tutorial - Lada Ada](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels)

[[WS2812 LED Strip] Adafruit Neopixel library slows down code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94723/adafruit-neopixel-library-slows-down-code)

***References***

[Using Using Neopixels with the Raspberry Pi](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/using-neopixels-with-the-raspberry-pi)

[WS2812B-V4 Intelligent control LED Integrated Light Source](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/108)

[AdaFrui NixoPixel Tutorial - Lada Ada](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels)

[AdaFruit NeoPixel Stick 8 x 5050 RGB LED with Integrated Drivers $5.95](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1426)

[Introducing OpenGarage: an Open-Source WiFi Garage Door Opener using ESP8266 - 55,426 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpwEa_48-Cw)

[Garage door buttons on car to control RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96187/garage-door-buttons-on-car-to-control-rpi)

[[WS2812 LED Strip] Adafruit Neopixel library slows down code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94723/adafruit-neopixel-library-slows-down-code)