# Controlling LEDStrip using Pi (3B+)

Tags: pi-3, gpio

[image][image][image]Yo, My name is Fabi,

Like 2 Months ago i started this "Project". I wanted to controll my LED Strip using my Pi. And this pi should host a Local webpage so i could control my led strip using any device in my Network. But unfortnetly im not very good at using Transistors, Cables, Grounds and stuff like that.

THE MAIN PROBLEM

I have wired everything correctly i think (i checked it like 20 times), i rewired everthing 4 to 5 times, too and it still doesnt work how it should. 
So there is this software called PIGPIO, and basically, if i want to controll a certain pin on the pi i have to type "pigs p (the pin in this case 17) 255(for the intensitiy of the color 0 till 255). Thats what i know, and i also understood. But if iam typing this into the console, the led still has the same color i dont know how to fix it.

please help !111!!!!1!1 :D

Thanks

Comment: A LED strip is not normally controlled by sending PWM.  Could you edit your question and include the model of LED strip you have bought.  Also a clear photo or photos showing the wiring between the Pi and the LED strip will be useful.

Comment: working on it i just took some pictures, thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: Add a link to the LED strip that you are using.

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XQ995VG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Hi@NKFabian， Ah, let me see.  Your Amazon LED strip has a 24 key remote, so there is no need to DIY: 
(3) LED strip RGB 10m SMD 5050 [24Key IR Remote]  €30 - Amazon 2019dec
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XQ995VG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1.

Comment: But if you wish to DIY, I suggest to start with Lady's newbie friendly tutorial: (1) The Magic of NeoPixels - Lady Ada 2013Papr
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels.

Comment: NeoPixel is a bit hard to control. You might like to the following LED strip question's answer  with a long list of references for DIY newbies: (1) Raspberry Pi and car led ground effects - 2019mar
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98555/raspberry-pi-and-car-led-ground-effects/98603#98603.

Comment: Your LED strip is 5050 based.  You can find AdaFruit's 5050 NeoPixel Stick LED strip description and tutorials: (4) NeoPixel Stick - 8 x 5050 RGB LED with Integrated Drivers - AdaFruit $6: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1426. I have a couples of LED x 8 strips in hand.  Show us the link to the tutorial your are following, and I can check out if they are compatible to Rpi4B buster Thonny python 3.7.3 (Sorry, I have no older versions of Rpi to reproduce your trouble).

Comment: In case you are using WS2812 to DIY your LED strip, you might like to refer to the SparkFun tutorial which is as good as Lady Ada: (1) https://imgur.com/gallery/Y4px8kF. Also refer to the following WS2812 Datasheet for wiring and control signals: 
(2) https://www.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/WS2812B-LED-datasheet.pdf.  Good luck and cheers. PS - Your 5050 guy is actually same as WS2828.

Comment: You may find the WS2812 LED datasheet hard to read.  You need to first understand the NRZ (Non Return to Zero) encoding protocol. Then you should find the datasheet "simple" !  :)   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero

Comment: If your LED strip is WS28xx based it can not be driven by pigpio.  You will need to find the precise controller chip of your strip to work out how to drive it.

Comment: Tutorial:https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/

Comment: You said 'the led still has the same color' what colour do you see? What happens if you unplug the red, green, blue cables in turn feeding the LEDs?

Comment: Your photo of the GPIO connections on your Pi has different connections than the tutorial that you are following !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have got confused between the pin numbering of the GPIO connections on the Pi. There are several conventions including BCM (Broadcom pin number, commonly called "GPIO") and Physical (Number corresponding to the pin's physical location on the header).

The tutorial is using the BCM numbering however you have placed your connections in the Physical pin locations.

The following site should help you relocate your GPIO connections to the correct BCM locations.

https://pinout.xyz