# Driving a WS2815 (12V, addressable) LED strip

Tags: led, mosfet

I am trying to plan what I need to drive a 12V addressable LED strip with the Raspberry Pi (4, likely, or zero, but I want Ethernet connectivity).

I am not sure I understand the [WS2815 datasheet (PDF)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwib7qrP9sfmAhWPO8AKHSqEDpAQFjAAegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.normandled.com%2Fupload%2F201808%2FWS2815%2520LED%2520Datasheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ugTxGvhMxQ6DpCNZelwc-) as I am not knowledgeable in electronics.
Pages 2 and 4 seems to say that VDD needs to be 12V.
Page 3 seems to imply that VDD is about 5V.

If my power supply is exactly 12V and Page 2 is the VDD I must have, the logic control voltages need to be below/above the 3.6V - 8.4V range.

And the current draw on the data channel is maximum 1 micro amp (page 3).

Data transfer time is approximately 1 microsecond per bit, so if I need a transistor or a MOSFET to drive the digital channel, I need it to be able to switch faster than 1MHz (possibly 10MHz).

**Q1/ Is my interpretation correct (12V logic, 10MHz switching capability necessary)?**

If so, **Q2/ what can I use to drive the logic? Can I use a ready made circuit with a single channel? Which/where?**

I have found this [8-channel 5V to 24V 10MHz converter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Converter-Module-8-Channel-SquareWave-Conversion/dp/B07RWK154G/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?keywords=signal%20level%20shifter%205v%20to%2012v&qid=1576634248&s=lighting&sr=8-2-fkmr0) and this other [8-channel 5V to 24V 10MHz converter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KEYREN-Conversion-8-Channel-SquareWave-Converter/dp/B081TT7SRP/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=optocoupler%2010MHz&qid=1576975762&sr=8-1), but I have not been able to find a (single channel, or any number of channels) 3.3V to 12V  10MHz converter.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  My answer to the following question, especially the reference section with Lady Ada's newbie friendly NeoPixel LED strip tutorial (1) https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels, might help: (2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98555/raspberry-pi-and-car-led-ground-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VCC is 5V VDD is 12V you need both.
the logic is referenced to VCC, so driving this will be similar to driving a WS2812 strip.